# Get a non-mapped data from the post's return

Tags: php, symfony

I have the segments checkbox in my form and when I submit, these values doesn't appears in post's return. The segment isn't mapped because it's a external value from database.

### Users.php (Entity)

```
/**
 * Users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_users_users_groups1_idx", columns={"users_groups_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Users
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=32, nullable=true)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="active", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $active;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var UsersGroups
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UsersGroups", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="users_groups_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $usersGroups;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->usersGroups = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

### UsersType.php (Form)

```
class UsersType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Nome',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                )
            ))
            ->add('email', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'E-mail',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                )
            ))
            ->add('password', 'password', array(
                'label' => 'Senha',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                )
            ))
            ->add('usersGroups', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Ad\SisBundle\Entity\UsersGroups',
                'label' => 'Grupo do usuário',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                )
            ))
            ->add('active', 'checkbox', array(
                'label' => 'Ativo',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                )
            ))
            ->add('segments', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Ad\SisBundle\Entity\Segments',
                'query_builder' => function( EntityRepository $segments ) {
                    return $segments->createQueryBuilder("s");
                },
                'multiple' => true,
                'mapped' => false,
                'expanded' => true,
            ))
        ;
    }
```

And this is the post's result

```
Users {#2011 ▼
  -name: "xxx"
  -email: "xxx@hotmail.com"
  -password: "312321"
  -active: true
  -createdAt: null
  -updatedAt: null
  -id: 1
  -usersGroups: UsersGroups {#2013 ▶}
}
```

I've tried this:

```
$segments = $editForm->get('segments')->getData();
```

I believe that if the segment information was the object of users, it would be easier to handle the information.

This is the right way to do this? How can I get the segment data?

Comment: have you tried $request->get('segments') ?

Answer (score 0):

If the segments are not mapped it won't passed to the entity.
you can either get it from the request in a preSubmit event subscriber(look at 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html#event-subscribers)
 or , changing mapped to true, and pass it to the entity but leave the field of the entity without the ORM annotation if you don't want it to be persisted.